# Why is the kinetic energy of the fragments of a fission determined entirely by the coulomb energy?

Tags: nuclear-physics

[This paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00838523) by P. A. Cherdantsev V. E. Marshalkin states

> ... there is no doubt that the knetic energy of fragments is wholly
>   caused by their Coulomb interections,...

How do we know that this is true?

If the semi empirical mass formula for the binding energy of the nucleus and

$$
E(A,Z) = a_1 A - a_2 A^{\frac{2}{3}} - a_3 \frac{Z^2}{A^{\frac{1}{3}}} - a_4 \frac{(2Z - A)^2}{A} 
$$

I think I can "prove" this for the case of a fission into two equal nuclei:

$$
2E\left(\frac{A}{2},\frac{Z}{2} \right) - E(A,Z) = \dots = -a_1A^{\frac{2}{3}}\cdot (2^{\frac{1}{3}} - 1) + a_2 \frac{Z^2}{A^{\frac{1}{3}}} \cdot ( 1- 2^{-\frac{2}{3}})
$$

Since $a_1 (2^{\frac{1}{3}} - 1) > 0$ and $a_3 ( 1- 2^{-\frac{2}{3}})$ one may conclude that in this case all released binding energy is due to the coulomb-term, in particular the kinetic energy of the products.

How to see the quote above for the general case? What are the standard arguments/evidence for the quote above?

Comment: Well, you could do the same considering a deformation parameter. I can develop this point in 1 hour or so if you want.

Comment: @T.Auerrac That would be great. But the asymetry term contribution will not vanish in that case?

Comment: I dont see the why should the mentioned sentence be true in GENERAL context...  Maybe I am missing something, correct me please.

Comment: Just because P. A. Cherdantsev V. E. Marshalkin don't mention any restriction for their statement.